# How to add an item to be displayed on a favourites page?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P3H0.png)

Upon tapping the heart at the top right of the container, how do I store it and display it on another page (the favourites page that is shown at the bottom of the picture)?

The container contains all the relevant details of the "restaurant" which I have stored in a Store class with attributes (String name, String price, String image).

Would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably employ some architecture in your app, like [Provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) or [BLoC](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern).

With Provider, you'll need to [lift your state (favourites) up](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up), so that both screens can access it by using [`Provider.of`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#providerof). I.e. put it somewhere above both of that screens in the tree of your widgets.

BLoC is similar, but it depends heavily on [`Streams`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream-class.html) and [`StreamBuilders`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to route changes from different parts of the app. You state (favourites) is also stored in once place, which is called BLoC (business logic component) in this case.

Comment: hey thanks for the help! using provider works however another problem that came up was that upon switching pages, my heart icon does not maintain its state. e.g. when i tap it and it turns red and the store is favourited and added into the favourites page, when i navigate to some other page and back, the icon is no longer red but empty (the favourited store is still favourited and can be viewed at the favourites page). any tips for this?